# Python 3 + GTK 4 - Buttons with pictures and labels look weird

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, gtk4

I develop a simple app for Linux, Kamarada Firstboot (source on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot)), using Python 3 and GTK, and I'm [migrating from GTK 3 to GTK 4](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html). In case you are curious, you can see it in action if you [download](https://linuxkamarada.com/en/download/) the Linux Kamarada ISO image and boot it using e.g. VirtualBox. The following screenshots are from the current version ([`15.3`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/tree/15.3/usr/share/kamarada-firstboot) branch), based on GTK 3.

[image]

[image]

I ported most of it to GTK 4 already ([`gtk4`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/tree/gtk4/usr/share/kamarada-firstboot) branch). But I'm facing an issue with the `GtkButton`'s, as since GTK 4 they don't have the `label` and `image` properties anymore, and to achieve the same appearance I need to use a combination of `GtkBox`, `GtkPicture` and `GtkLabel`.

But although all my `GtkButton`'s have similar sources:

```xml
      <object class="GtkButton" id="btnPortuguese">
        <property name="child">
          <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
            <property name="margin-end">10</property>
            <property name="margin-start">10</property>
            <property name="margin-top">10</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="spacing">10</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkPicture" id="imgPortuguese">
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="valign">start</property>
              </object>  
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel">
                <property name="label">Português Brasileiro</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </property>
        <layout>
          <property name="column">0</property>
          <property name="row">2</property>
        </layout>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="onBtnPortugueseClicked"/>
      </object>
```

Each of them look differently:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to both Python and GTK, but I have some experience programming.

I believe the most relevant files for this question are: [`kamarada-firstboot.py`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/blob/20ca8223b57d7d48bc5e173e559b7570f16c12eb/usr/share/kamarada-firstboot/kamarada-firstboot.py) and [`kamarada-firstboot.ui`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/blob/20ca8223b57d7d48bc5e173e559b7570f16c12eb/usr/share/kamarada-firstboot/kamarada-firstboot.ui).

Here's how one can easily get started with the project (supposing Git, Python 3 and GTK 4 are installed already):

```
$ git clone https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot.git
$ cd firstboot
$ git checkout gtk4
$ cd usr/share/kamarada-firstboot
$ python3 kamarada-firstboot.py
```

When the program ends, it outputs the user choices to `~/.config/kamarada-firstboot`. You may want to delete this file between tests.

Comment: Completely off-topic, but using flags to represent languages is all but guaranteed to alienate entire ethnic groups.

Comment: Looks like your problem is related to how the containers manage padding/ sizing on gtk4 https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#stop-using-gtkbox-padding-fill-and-expand-child-properties

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @GonzaloOdiard. In my last commit ([`d767786c`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/commit/d767786c684298ea3afdf653de405c667de7d3ae)), I tried the `margin-*`, `halign` and `valign` properties your link suggests. I made some progress, the buttons look less weird now, but still weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [GTK Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector) on some [GNOME core apps](https://apps.gnome.org/) and studying their source codes, I found a solution.

Each software listed in [GNOME Software](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Software) corresponds to a [`GsSummaryTile`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/blob/f6c8d34d217b77cbd681b28cf26dc19823535662/src/gs-summary-tile.ui), which inherits from [`GsAppTile`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-software/-/blob/f6c8d34d217b77cbd681b28cf26dc19823535662/src/gs-app-tile.ui), whose parent is the `GtkButton`. So, we are seeing buttons here:

[image]

The `GsSummaryTile` uses a `GtkGrid` (not a `GtkBox`, as I was trying to do) to pack the `GtkImage` and the `GtkLabel`'s together.

I did that inside the buttons:

```xml
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btnPortuguese">
            <property name="child">
              <object class="GtkGrid">
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="margin-bottom">12</property>
                <property name="margin-top">12</property>
                <property name="row-spacing">12</property>
                <property name="valign">center</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkPicture" id="imgPortuguese">
                    <property name="halign">center</property>
                    <property name="valign">end</property>
                    <layout>
                      <property name="column">0</property>
                      <property name="row">0</property>
                    </layout>
                  </object>  
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel">
                    <property name="justify">center</property>
                    <property name="label">Português Brasileiro</property>
                    <property name="valign">start</property>
                    <layout>
                      <property name="column">0</property>
                      <property name="row">1</property>
                    </layout>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </property>
            <!-- ... -->
          </object>
```

[image]

And to make the buttons have the same width and height, I put them inside a `GtkGrid` with `column-homogeneous` and `row-homogeneous` set to `True`:

```xml
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="column-homogeneous">True</property>
        <property name="column-spacing">24</property>
        <property name="row-homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btnPortuguese">
          <!-- ... -->
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btnEnglish">
          <!-- ... -->
        </child>
      </object>
```

With the buttons on the second stack, I did a similar solution, but with one detail: I split the button in half and put the icon on the first (upper) half and the label on the second (bottom) half, setting `row-homogeneous` to `True` on the inner `GtkGrid`, `valign` to `end` on the `GtkPicture` and `valign` to `start` on the `GtkLabel`.

[image]

```xml
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btnInstall">
            <property name="halign">fill</property>
            <property name="valign">fill</property>
            <property name="child">
              <object class="GtkGrid">
                <property name="halign">center</property>
                <property name="margin-bottom">12</property>
                <property name="margin-top">12</property>
                <property name="row-homogeneous">True</property>
                <property name="valign">center</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkPicture" id="imgInstall">
                    <property name="halign">center</property>
                    <property name="valign">end</property>
                    <layout>
                      <property name="column">0</property>
                      <property name="row">0</property>
                    </layout>
                  </object>  
                </child>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbInstallButton">
                    <property name="justify">center</property>
                    <property name="label">Install Linux Kamarada</property>
                    <property name="margin-top">12</property>
                    <property name="valign">start</property>
                    <layout>
                      <property name="column">0</property>
                      <property name="row">1</property>
                    </layout>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </property>
            <!-- ... -->
          </object>
```

I believe I summarized the main ideas of my solution.

You can see the full source here: [`kamarada-firstboot.ui`](https://gitlab.com/kamarada/firstboot/-/blob/9ffac31ff56a2f487d0aeb6f651194f03beeea31/usr/share/kamarada-firstboot/kamarada-firstboot.ui).